# Solr with NetBeans

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, solr

I have developed a JSP web application using NetBeans IDE and a Virtuoso RDBMS.
Now i would like to integrate Solr into it.
I have installed Solr 3.3.0 from http://apache.favoritelinks.net//lucene/solr/
Should i just copy the war file from the downloaded directory to my web application web-inf directory ?

I am using windows7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the Jetty server that comes with Solr for running it. Just go into the solr catalog and run `java -jar solr.jar` This will startup the server locally.

You also need to configure Solr. There are a lot of threads on this and the Solr wiki is good as well. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/

Comment: Then just drop it in the webapps folder on tomcat and it will autodeploy it.

Comment: i did, but when i start the server using Netbeans , it says context /solr/ not found

Comment: but when i try to run tomcat manually using cmd startup, i am able to start solr.Can the reason be that I have configured Netbeans to run tomcat on 8084, while when i run tomcat from cmd it runs on 8080??

Comment: I am no NetBeans user at all so that I can't answer. Sorry.

Comment: ok I have been able to start Solr, but my orignal question still remains unanswered, in order to use it with my existing web application what do i do?

Comment: should i include the "jar" file in the library of my web application?

Comment: No you need to setup indexing. Feed data to Solr. There is no magic involved. Need to use the config files. Look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ for more information.